# ORACLE SQL Developer Update Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

```
UPDATE QITEM 
   SET QTYONHAND = QTYONHAND + (SELECT SUM(DELQTY)
                                  FROM QDEL 
                                 WHERE QITEM.ITEMNAME = QDEL.ITEMNAME);
```

I am trying to update  an inventory column where the intial values are all 1000 and I am adding the number of deliveries from the **QDEL** table to that 1000. This works but there are null values present in the rows with no deliveries in the **QDEL** table. I cannot figure out why???

Answer (score 2):

Because `SUM` returns `NULL` if all `DELQTY` rows are `NULL`. You can do something like this :

```
UPDATE QITEM 
SET QTYONHAND = QTYONHAND + COALESCE((SELECT SUM(DELQTY)
FROM QDEL 
WHERE QITEM.ITEMNAME = QDEL.ITEMNAME), 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `WHERE EXISTS` so you're only updating rows where there is at least one corresponding record in `QDEL`:

```
UPDATE qitem qi
   SET qi.qtyonhand = qi.qtyonhand + ( SELECT SUM(qd.delqty)
                                         FROM qdel qd
                                        WHERE qd.itemname = qi.itemname )
 WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM qdel qd
                 WHERE qd.itemname = qi.itemname );
```

P.S. If it's possible for the value of `delqty` in `QDEL` to be NULL, you'll want to use `SUM(NVL(qd.delqty, 0))` (or `SUM(COALESCE(qd.delqty, 0))`) rather than `SUM(qd.delqty)`.

Answer (score 1):

Use NVL to always return a sum, even if no deliveries have taken place.

```
UPDATE QITEM 
SET QTYONHAND = QTYONHAND + (SELECT NVL(SUM(DELQTY),0)
    FROM QDEL 
    WHERE QITEM.ITEMNAME = QDEL.ITEMNAME);
```